# android 5.0 google ads nullpoint

Tags: android, ads

Google Ads work on 4.4 but on 5.0 it crashes.

this is my google ads code:

```
        // Create an ad.
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdUnitId(GlobalVars.ADS_UNIT_AD);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
        adView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
        // until the ad is loaded.
        if (null == mRootLayout) {
            mRootLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_frame_layout);
        }
        mRootLayout.addView(adView);

        // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device
        // ID to
        // get test ads on a physical device.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        // Start loading the ad in the background.
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Here's the error log:
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize com.google.android.gms.internal.ay.bc()' on a null object reference
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.bh.getAdSize(Unknown Source)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.getAdSize(Unknown Source)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    11-17 06:29:35.451: E/AndroidRuntime(28686):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

Comment: Post the code that you use for this ad.

Comment: Looks like a [known bug](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/lL-FlIxfvyI/4f9mTENjDHAJ).